# Change Block view using custom Views

Tags: 8, views, blocks

I have one content type(Contains Image & body field). for that, I have created a custom block view using Views. currently, it's showing content like on the left side the image is placed and on the right side, the body content is placed. I have added content 4 times for that content type. now I want to show that content like:

```
    LEFT           RIGHT

    image          body
    body           image
    image          body
    body           image
```

**Can I achieve this using Views or do I need to add custom code or anything else?**

I am new to drupal. Please help me with this.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want to do, but you can edit the order of the fields into the view itself, in particular from the section fields (if you had set the view as fields):

[image: [![Using fields into the view][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BThU.png]